# Insert today's date in cell (command + ;) defaults to nonsensical 1900 date in mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, mac, office-for-mac

I know `ctrl+;` (windows) and `cmd+;` (mac) will insert today's date on the current active cell in excel.

I'm facing a problem where it's inserting 1/0/1900  11:01:00 PM:
[image]

Very confusing. Does anyone know how to fix/debug this?

Comment: What version of Excel? Are you using a standard US keyboard? Have you run repair on Excel (excel.exe /safe)?

Comment: @JG7 I have version 16.46 (21021202). It's a fresh installation of office on a brand new mac. Standard input keyboard.

Comment: 1) What does the `NOW()` function produce as a result? 2) Does the same odd date time occur in any cell, no matter the number formatting selected?

Comment: @JG7 @Jeorje - the `NOW()` function returns the right date, but this is not an alternative, as it will be recalculated every time I open the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It's an internal procedure for Excel. Just asks the system the date and provides it to you.

Therefore, there are really only two possibilities:

1. Excel is failing somehow. Given the ne machine and fresh install, that seems extremely unlikely.
2. The computer is telling Excel that is the date. Given it is a new computer, no history of providing the right date for X years and now suddenly giving a wrong one, but rather a short history in which this is likely the first real test of what date is has.

Therefore, you should check the system date. Especially if, over the several days since you posted, the date Excel gives you is advanced from the 0 in your post.

(I will add the caveat that it can be... hard (Foolish? A mug's game? Well, sometimes it must be done anyway, 'cause... "real life" and all that.)... to narrow something in a computer down to two possibilities. When there could be 40,000 strange little quirks available. But the above are the only two possibilities that seem to have any non-"vanishingly small" possibility to them.)

Comment: Thanks @Jeorje, as I mentioned in my comment above, the `NOW()` function returns the right date, so... ¿

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on debugging this?